# Display the distribution of two groups on the same plot, using two data frames

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have a data frame of `scores`, it has 2000 rows and 25 columns. The columns are features and rows are samples. This data frame will be the data I use to plot the distributions.

In another data frame,`metadata`, I have clinical information about each sample in the `scores` data frame, like gender, age, type of diease, treatment, and most importantly outcome to treatment. This data frame will serve as labels, it gives the label for each sample.

The two dataframe have the exact same samples.

There are three columns that describe a different kind of response to each sample, and those columns are binrary, yes or no.

My target is to make a distribution plot for the samples that belong to the yes or no groups, in each of those 3 columns.

Here is an example. Say this is `scores`:

```
                  Feature_1        Feature_2        Feature_3
Patient_1            0.56             0.11             0.03
Ptient_2             0.605             0.34            0.49
P_3                  0.1              0.76             0.42
12312AX              0.9              0.382            0.12
P_10                 0.89             0.30             0.119
12312BX              0.232            0.118            0.80
12312CX              0.679            0.31             0.789
```

And this is `metadata`:

```
                  Gender        Age        Outcome1       Outcome2        Outcome3

Patient_1           M           54            1              0                0
Ptient_2            M           28            0              0                1
P_3                 F           32            1              1                0
12312AX             F           87            0              0                1
P_10                F           43            0              0                1
12312BX             M           90            1              1                0             
12312CX             F           65            1              0                0
```

Now, for example, I want to plot `Feature_1` for the sameples that are `Outcome1 = 1` vs the samples that are with label`Outcome1 = 0`, and put them on the same plot to see the difference. A plot that would look like this:

[image]

It doesn't matter if it's not filled with color.

This is some subset of the data. Starting with `scores`:

```
structure(list(`Feature_1` = c(0.58126387599574, 0.554773857342486, 
0.73811669435931, 0.5993561705421, 0.549993884896126, 0.560952809292699, 
0.514920708901865, 0.668611976328753, 0.579311040856707, 0.627079649056927, 
0.549778821698995, 0.563433551362653, 0.566883741540508, 0.586839499814986, 
0.527874599585146, 0.533974585406425, 0.583020804822263, 0.607821542253184, 
0.570922624085177, 0.531065608748296), `Feature_2` = c(0.671868971517913, 
0.657649690364772, 0.681277871841209, 0.633247301225077, 0.658829966989863, 
0.649553434195565, 0.654719152272398, 0.678510931368968, 0.67606269281911, 
0.657861486037168, 0.656157657102225, 0.654684442044789, 0.660668253143108, 
0.680000904001928, 0.676215636114716, 0.68015840395165, 0.656533748483226, 
0.654344382579621, 0.626207872177309, 0.640129803823085), `Feature10` = c(0.607691853076, 
0.507746766229958, 0.642056075026442, 0.647793952813017, 0.571844979370279, 
0.592183904204232, 0.473827520445559, 0.618900091543045, 0.60656936545554, 
0.60603612041945, 0.510241627095173, 0.564418205496303, 0.561084611266194, 
0.558495659089567, 0.503235910349171, 0.492768739941572, 0.551283907128425, 
0.664425637003928, 0.541804175576185, 0.537845283573044)), row.names = c("Pt1", 
"Pt10", "Pt101", "Pt103", "Pt106", "Pt11", "Pt17", "Pt18", "Pt2", 
"Pt24", "Pt26", "Pt27", "Pt28", "Pt29", "Pt3", "Pt30", "Pt31", 
"Pt34", "Pt36", "Pt37"), class = "data.frame")
```

And the `metadata`:

```
structure(list(Response = c("No", "No", "Yes", 
"No", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", 
"No", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", 
"No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", 
"No", "No"), Gender = c("F", "M", 
"F", "M", "M", "F", "M", 
"M", "F", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "F", "F", "M", "F", 
"F", "M", "F"), Response2 = c(1, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c("Pt1", 
"Pt10", "Pt101", "Pt103", "Pt106", "Pt11", "Pt17", "Pt18", "Pt2", 
"Pt24", "Pt26", "Pt27", "Pt28", "Pt29", "Pt3", "Pt30", "Pt31", 
"Pt34", "Pt36", "Pt37"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using ggplot2 package. So first merge the data by rownames, and then you can plot it with ggplot

```
# Merge by rownames
df <- merge(score, metadata, by=0, all=TRUE)
# Plot 
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Feature_1, fill=Response)) + geom_density(alpha=.3)
```

[image]

If your categorical data is numerical ("0" or "1" instead of "Yes" "No", you can turn the variable into factor:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Feature_1, fill=factor(Response2))) + geom_density(alpha=.3)
```